# asp.net Validate userinput but keep fields

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

What I am working on is a timereporting system just to get a better hang of asp.net mvc5 and javascript etc.
This is my view:
[image]

If Timmar: on Projekt 1 doesn't match up with "Tid Jobbad:" it will get sent to the backend and check so that the hours are correct. If they do not add up I return an error message like this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + project.First(), "Antalet timmar stämmer ej överrens.");
```

But that also means that my view is reset to the original state, but what I want to do I want to keep all the fields I did enter and still get the error message.

I guess I could write a javascript that does this check instead, but is it such a good idea to have Javascript do checkings like this since you can tamper with that rather easy?

And this is my controller and how I currently validate the hours.

```
private NewTimeReportModel ReportDates(FormCollection form, NewTimeReportModel projectData, List<string> dates, bool? noTimeToReport)
    {
        foreach (string date in dates)
        {
            DateTime reportDate;
            bool? noTime = noTimeToReport;

            if (!DateTime.TryParse(date, out reportDate))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Inget datum valt");
            }
            else
            {
                var projectNumbers = (from x in form.AllKeys where x.Contains("_") select x.Substring(x.IndexOf('_'))).Distinct();

                projectData.Times = new TimeReportTimes(form["startTime"], form["endTime"], form["breakTime"], ModelState);
                projectData.Date = reportDate;

                //Will never be null.
                if (noTime != null)
                {
                    projectData.NoTimeToReport = (bool)noTime;

                    if (!(bool)noTime)
                    {
                        //Validates so the user put in the right amount of hours, and did chosoe a project.
                        ValidateUserInput(form, projectData, projectNumbers);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form["ReportId"]))
                        {
                            projectData.ReportId = Guid.Parse(form["ReportId"]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //If we get this far everything is ok and we save the timereport to the database
                    projectData.SaveToDatabase(Constants.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name));
                    ViewData["posted"] = true;
                    projectData = new NewTimeReportModel();
                }
                else if (projectData.Projects.Count == 1)
                {
                    projectData.Projects[0].Hours = null;
                }
            }
        }

        return projectData;
    }
    private void ValidateUserInput(FormCollection form, NewTimeReportModel projectData, IEnumerable<string> projectNumbers)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> project = projectNumbers as string[] ?? projectNumbers.ToArray();
        if (!project.Any())
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Projekt", "Inga projekt valda...");
        }
        else
        {
            int emptyHours = 0;
            foreach (string projectNumber in project)
            {
                projectData.Projects.Add(new NewTimeReportModel.Project
                {
                    Description = form["description" + projectNumber],
                    Hours = null,
                    ProjectId = Guid.Parse(form["project" + projectNumber])
                });

                string hourString = form["hours" + projectNumber];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hourString))
                {
                    emptyHours++;
                    int count = project.Count();
                    if (count > 1)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + projectNumber, "Du måste skriva in tid på alla project.");
                    }
                    projectData.Projects[projectData.Projects.Count - 1].Hours = projectData.Times.WorkedHours;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!projectData.Projects[projectData.Projects.Count - 1].SetHours(hourString))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + projectNumber, "Felaktig antal timmar.");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (emptyHours > 1 || (emptyHours == 0 && projectData.Projects.Sum(x => x.Hours) != projectData.Times.WorkedHours))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + project.First(), "Antalet timmar stämmer ej överrens.");
            }

            if (projectData.Projects.Any(x => x.Hours <= 0))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + project.First(), "Antalet timmar jobbade måste vara större än noll.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can do this by remote validation. go through google for remote validation in mvc

Comment: @Arvaan Will do, going to check it out now. I did not know this were a thing.

Comment: You can call backend method for checking validation directly by view. Just like we check email is already exists in database while registration, without  going to server side
you can check example here
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/669824/Implementing-Remote-Validation-in-MVC

Comment: @Arvaan My model is built in such a way so I'm nbt sure if would be ann easy task to mplement that.

Comment: Can I see your controller code??

Comment: @Arvaan Sure thing, updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning only view, return view with model something like this
Return View(model);

Check the below link to get your the code
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710702/ASP-NET-MVC-Server-Side-Validation

Comment: I had to change around in my controller a bit, but I did get it working later thanks to you.

Comment: Or well, almost. Hehe.